# Create a List of a certain type in Boo

Tags: list, boo

I tried

```
public class Chest(Item):
    public contents as Item
```

But that's of course a single Item, not a list. How do I declare `contents` as a list of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics, like this:

```
import System.Collections.Generic

class Chest(Item):
  contents as List[of Item]
```

PS you shouldn't expose fields as public on classes. [Create a property instead](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Part+08+-+Classes#Part08-Classes-FieldsandProperties).

Comment: In this case, creating a property would just be a glorified public variable. Thanks for the answer, works perfect.